# Passing an options hash to a sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I remember when I tried passing a params (JSON) option to a sidekiq worker method and it didn't work out well because I was referencing the option like:

```
options[:email_address]
```

But I think it would have worked if I did:

```
options["email_address"]
```

So for some reason when it gets serialized and deserialized the hash can only be referenced with a string not a symbol.

**Is this a safe practise?**

I have a transaction email worker that looks like:

```
class TransactionEmailWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(action, options)
    case action
    when 'welcome'
      welcome(options["email_address"], options["something_else"])
    when 'reset_password'
      reset_password(options["email_address"])
    end
  end

  def welcome(email, title)
    # ...
  end

  def reset_password(email)
   # ..
  end
```

Answer (score 26):

This is what the Sidekiq [wiki page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple) states:

> The arguments you pass to `perform_async` must be composed of simple JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and hash. The Sidekiq client API uses `JSON.dump` to send the data to Redis. The Sidekiq server pulls that JSON data from Redis and uses `JSON.load` to convert the data back into Ruby types to pass to your perform method.  Don't pass symbols, named parameters or complex Ruby objects (like Date or Time!) as those will not survive the dump/load round trip correctly.

Passing a Ruby hash is valid as it is able to serialize into valid JSON. So to answer your question, it's safe practice.

```rb
serialized_args = JSON.dump({email_address: "someemailaddress@gmail.com", something_else: "thing"})
=> "{\"email_address\":\"someemailaddress@gmail.com\",\"something_else\":\"thing\"}"

JSON.load(serialized_args)
=> {"email_address"=>"someemailaddress@gmail.com", "something_else"=>"thing"}
```

Answer (score 14):

Job parameters must be valid JSON types:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple

Comment: so using a hash is bad practise? (as described above in my Q)

Comment: Using a hash is not bad practice; using symbols is.

Comment: Using Sidekiq is bad practice! I'm joking but it's just such a stupid design decision, you follow Ruby conventions like using keyword arguments and Sidekiq silently passes something else, breaking your app despite all specs passing (running inline). I wish they supported a better serialiser, like Rails.cache does.